# Getting an attribute of grandparent class using getattr

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm trying to access an instance attribute (`inst_baseA / inst_baseB`) of `Base` class from an instance of `ClassB`, depending on an attribute of the instance (`self.x` of object ClassB).

Here is my code:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inst_baseA = 'base_B'
        self.inst_baseB = 'base_A'


class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.node = Base()


class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassB, self).__init__()
        self.x = 'base_A'
```

This is what I tried first:

```
>>> b = ClassB()
>>> getattr(b, 'node.inst_{}'.format(b.x))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    getattr(b, 'node.inst_{}'.format(b.x))
AttributeError: 'ClassB' object has no attribute 'node.inst_base_A'
```

I overcome this if I chain calls to getattr:

```
>>> getattr(getattr(b, 'node'), b.x)
'base_A'
```

*Out of curiosity*: Is there a way to get an attribute of the Base class from grandchildren class besides doing *two* calls to `getattr`?

---

Update: the reason I need it is I'm trying to:
- Get an attribute fron grandparent class (either inst_baseA or inst_baseB)
- Depending on an attribute on my instance (the value of x)

So my code is actually something like: `getattr(self, 'node.{}'.format(self.x))`. I didn't explain it correctly at the first time, hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: `getattr(b.node, 'inst_base')` or even simpler `b.node.inst_base`?

Comment: @MSeifert I've updated my question to reflect my situation. I didn't do it right on the first time :)

Comment: Why not just `getattr(self.node, self.x)`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey this works.. don't know how I didn't see it myself. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter), but it's really not meant for this kind of thing, so the syntax is pretty awkward:

```
>>> operator.attrgetter('node.inst_base')(b)
'base'
```

But this is really quite unintuitive, so to avoid confusing people who read your code, it's probably better to roll your own multi-getattr instead:

```
def get_multi_attr(obj, attrs):
    for attr in attrs.split('.'):
        obj = getattr(obj, attr)
    return obj
```

```
>>> get_multi_attr(b, 'node.inst_base')
'base'
```

Comment: thanks. I've updated my question to reflect my situation better. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 2):

According to [[Python]: **getattr**(*object, name[, default]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

> Return the value of the named attribute of *object*. *name* must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`.

`node.inst_base` is **not** an attribute of `b`, but:

- `node` is an attribute of `b`
- `inst_base` is an attribute of `b.node`

So, you need one `getattr` call for each "nesting" level.

Considering that I've pasted your code in the interpreter's interactive window:

> ```
> >>> getattr(b, 'node.inst_base')
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> AttributeError: 'ClassB' object has no attribute 'node.inst_base'
> >>>
> >>> getattr(getattr(b, "node", None), "inst_base", None)
> 'base'
> ```

Or, to take things further, you can create a getter that works with "nested" attribute names:

> ```
> >>> def getattr_nested(obj, nested_attr):
> ...     attrs = nested_attr.split(".")
> ...     ret = obj
> ...     for attr in attrs:
> ...             ret = getattr(ret, attr, None)
> ...             if ret is None:
> ...                     return None
> ...     return ret
> ...
> >>>
> >>> getattr_nested(b, "node.inst_base")
> 'base'
> >>> getattr_nested(b, "node.inst_base2")
> >>> getattr_nested(b, "node")
> <__main__.Base object at 0x0000021A2A593D30>
> ```

But that's probably highly inefficient (and also, doesn't handle corner cases), and you'd better use @Aran-Fey's suggestion.