# Efficient way to access class nested attrbibutes

Tags: python, class, nested-attributes

Consider that we have 5 python classes X1, X2, X3, X4, X5 and the following code:

```
class Schedule:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class DateBound:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr3 = Schedule()


class Behavior:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr2 = DateBound()


class Host:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = Behavior()

class PeriodController:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr0 = Host()
```

Now suppose a function in **PeriodController** needs to access attr3 of class **DateBound** :

```
class PeriodController:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr0 = ()

    def example_function(self):
        return self.attr0.attr1.attr2.attr3
```

How would I efficiently access **attr3** in such a situation ? I have nothing against accessing it like the **example_function()**, but it does not seem right because of the repetition of **attr0.attr1 ... attrn**

Briefly, the conception of this implementation is that a **Host** has a **Bahavior** that defines among others at which time he should be connected to the server.

The **DateBound** class exists, because sometimes a Host can be connected to the server at a different time from its normal **Behavior** time, but it is indeed the good Host, hence none regular connection times of the **Host** are specified using a **Datebound** instance.

A **DateBound** has a **Schedule** which contains the times which a **DateBound** instance has, hence the times the **Host** should be connected. 
Finally the **PeriodController**, controls if the **Host** is connected according to its normal **Behavior**, thus **PeriodController** needs to access self.attr3

Comment: Will there always only be one attribute for each class?

Comment: If `X5` needs access to an attribute in `X2`, then something is wrong with your design.

Comment: No. There will be more attributes, but only one attribute of type X4(self.attr0), X3(self.attr2), X2(...) and X1(...) respectively to each class.

Comment: You might be right @chepner , but I do not see how to implement the design in any other way.

Comment: It's almost impossible to tell from an artificial example like this what the correct design should be. Without more context, I don't see how anyone could suggest anything other than the explicit chain you already have.

Comment: What do you mean by efficiently? Accessing an attribute of a class is done by `instance.attribute` (well, most common). How would you like to access it? It doesn't seem right from performance or code perspective? You could take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724176/getting-an-attribute-of-grandparent-class-using-getattr.

Comment: I will update my question.

Comment: @CristiFati I was referring to code perspective, definitely, because in terms of algorithm complexity I doubt that something would change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
class X5:
  def __init__(self):
    self.attr0 = X4()
  def example_function(self, count = 1):
    if count == 4:
      return self.attr0
    self.attr0 = getattr(self.attr0, f'attr{count}')
    return self.example_function(count+1)

print(X5().example_function())
```

Output:

```
<__main__.X1 object at 0x1012cc278>
```

Printing `X5().attr0.attr1.attr2.attr3)` achieves the same result:

```
<__main__.X1 object at 0x1012cc278>
```

Adding `__repr__` methods to each class makes for easier visualization:

```
class X1:
  ...
  def __repr__(self):
    return f'<{self.__class__.__name__}>'

print(X5().example_function())
```

Output:

```
<X1>
```

Comment: I doubt the attributes are really named `attr0` through `attr3`, and this function clobbers `self.attr0`.

Comment: @user2357112 That is a possibility, and probably the best way to handle that is simply regular attribute lookup. However, based on the OP's recent edit describing the use case for his code, it seems that there really does exist an `attr3`, and in my option increases the likelyhood that there truly does exist all attributes as originally listed.

Answer (score 1):

Although Ajax beat me, I was working on a niftier solution:

```
def examplefunction(startObject, differenceInX):
    for _ in range(differenceInX + 1):
        startObject = getattr(startObject, (any(item.startswith('attr') for item in dir(startObject))[0])
    return startObject
```

This should be defined outside of any classes.

Usage:
`startObject` would be an instance of `X5()` in this case, and `differenceInX` would be 5 - 2 = 3.

The good thing about this method is that it can be used for any class without having to define it repeatedly. Note that `(any(item.startswith('attr') for item in dir(startObject))[0])` relies on there only being one attribute beginning with `'attr'` for each class (in this case, the `attr0/1/2/3/n`).

Comment: I suspect the "only one defined attribute for each class" restriction is unlikely to be satisfied.

Comment: I need to use it inside a class @Adi219 , nevertheless I might also need in the future to use such a function for any class instance so, thank you :)

Comment: No problem :-))